# Mysql - Remove numbers before all occurrence of # character

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql output like below

```
1#D3D3D3,200#49a74c,31#D3D3D3,4000#D3D3D3,5#f81a27
```

I would like to remove the numbers before all occurrence of #.
The expected output will be like below

```
#D3D3D3,#49a74c,#D3D3D3,#D3D3D3,#f81a27
```

This didn't work.
set @data= "1#D3D3D3,2#49a74c,3#D3D3D3,4#D3D3D3,5#f81a27";
select @data;
SELECT SUBSTR(@data, INSTR(@data, '#')) AS column1;

please advise how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: can you please show the structure of your table and the query you're using?

Comment: This is an output of GROUP_CONCAT. And its coming from multiple queries. Its basically a color code from # and the number before it is its sorting. And after i have done a order by on this output i want to remove the number before #

Comment: Not sure how to share because its a 400 line stored procedure.

Comment: Please provide the version and more details of DB & Table

Comment: set @data= "1#D3D3D3,2#49a74c,3#D3D3D3,4#D3D3D3,5#f81a27";
select @data;

Comment: My sql 8 with InnoDB engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will remove the string before `#`

replace `@data` with the column name

```
SELECT SUBSTR(@data", INSTR(@data, '#')) AS column;
```

with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTR(@data, INSTR(@data, '#'))) AS column;
```

after `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
set @data= "1#D3D3D3,2#49a74c,3#D3D3D3,4#D3D3D3,5#f81a27"; 
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(@data, ',?[a-z0-9]*#', ',#'), 2) as col
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the removal should happen after group-concat has happened

Comment: set @data= "1#D3D3D3,2#49a74c,3#D3D3D3,4#D3D3D3,5#f81a27";
select @data;
SELECT SUBSTR(@data, INSTR(@data, '#')) AS column1;

Comment: for that, you have to use `REGEX_REPLACE`

Comment: Sorry Ravi, following didn't work      set @data= "1#D3D3D3,2#49a74c,3#D3D3D3,4#D3D3D3,5#f81a27";
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@data, '/,?[a-z0-9]*#/g', '#') as col

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221389/discussion-between-arvi-and-amit).